# speed difference for pd.to_datetime for 2 different formats

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have 2 different date columns in my dataframe that I want to convert to datetime64.

One has the format

```
0    2009-03-09
```

and is converted rather fast:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.acquisition_date)
10000 loops, best of 3: 97.9 µs per loop
```

The other one has this format:

```
0    2013-01-07 01:02:38 UTC
```

and its conversion takes approx. 18 times longer:

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.created_at)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.74 ms per loop
```

What can I do to speed this up?

Edit:
Some results from the suggestions (`df.created_at` is the `slow` format):

```
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.acquisition_date)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.created_at)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, infer_datetime_format=True)
%timeit pd.to_datetime(df.created_at, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
10000 loops, best of 3: 98.5 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.73 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 955 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 222 µs per loop
```

Comment: try passing infer_datetime_format=True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it explicit when you can.

```
 > dates = pd.Series(['2013-01-07 01:02:38 UTC']*100000)
 > %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates)
 ^C
 > %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')
 1 loops, best of 3: 570 ms per loop
```

Oddly, this seems to hurt the other kind.

```
> dates = pd.Series(['2009-03-09']*100000)
> %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.2 ms per loop
> %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates, format='%Y-%m-%d')
1 loops, best of 3: 342 ms per loop
```

Note that the preferred form for your long-form timestamps gets us back up to speed:

```
> dates = pd.Series(['2013-01-07T01:02:38Z']*100000)
> %timeit pd.to_datetime(dates)
10 loops, best of 3: 23.1 ms per loop
```